# Limit amount of bar graphs in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Im creating this bar plot, the problem is that I have +1000 bars in the graphic, how can I limit it to an specific value? display 10 bars only

```
df.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(50,40))
plt.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='green')
plt.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')
plt.show()
```

Comment: presumably you have 1000+ datapoints in your dataframe. So how would you want to only plot 10. Pick 10 at random? The first 10? The last 10? Average some of the bars together to get 10? Please provide some more details on what your expected outcome is, and perhaps what your data looks like

Comment: Hi!. First 10 or 10 random, I just need to show some of the values ​​from my total results. Im comparing predicted values vs actual values, so any of those would work.

Comment: Just `data[:10].plot(kind='bar')`? Or `data[::len(data)//10].plot(kind='bar')`?

Comment: Perfect man, thanks!!!